# Automatically block DOS attacks in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, denial-of-service

I would like to know what is the best and the easiest solution 
to protect http server deployed on AWS cloud against DOS attacks

I know that there is AWS Advanced Shield 
that can be turned on for that purpose 
however it is too expensive (3000$ per month) 
 
https://aws.amazon.com/shield/pricing/


**System architecture**

HTTP request -> Application Load Balancer -> EC2

- Nginx server is installed on this machine
- Nginx server is configured with rate limiting
- Nginx server responds with 429 code when too many requests are send from one IP
- Nginx server is generating log files (access.log, error.log)
- AmazonCloudWatchAgent is installed on this machine
- AmazonCloudWatchAgent listen on log files
- AmazonCloudWatchAgent send changes from log files to specific CloudWatch Log groups
- Logs from all EC2 machines are centralized in on place (CloudWatch Log groups)

I can configure CloudWatch Logs Metric Filters 
to send me alarms when too many 429 requests happen from one IP number 
In that way I can manually block particular IP in Network ACL 
and cut off all requests from bad IP number in a lower network layer 
and protect my AWS resources from being drained 

I would like to do it somehow automatically 
What is the easiest and the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/de/answers/networking/aws-ddos-attack-mitigation/

Answer (score 1):

Note that, per the [AWS Shield pricing documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/pricing/):

> AWS Shield Standard provides protection for all AWS customers from
>   common, most frequently occurring network and transport layer DDoS
>   attacks that target your web site or application at no additional
>   charge.

For a more comprehensive discussion on DDoS mitigation, see:

- [Denial of Service Attack Mitigation on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-ddos-attack-mitigation/)
- [AWS Best Practices for DDoS Resiliency](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/DDoS_White_Paper.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is no one straightforward way to block DDOS to your infrastructure. However, there are a few techniques and best practices which you can follow to at least protect the infrastructure. DDOS attacks can be stopped by analyzing and patching it at the same moment.

You may consider using external services listed below to block ddos at some extent:

> Cloudflare: https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/ddos/
>
> Imperva Incapsula:
>   https://www.imperva.com/products/ddos-protection-services/

I have tried both in the production system and they are pretty decent. Cloudflare is right now handling 10% of total internet traffic, they know about the good and bad traffic.

They are not much expensive comparative to shield. You may integrate it with your infrastructure as a code in order to automate for all of your services.

```
Disclaimer: I am not associated in any way with any of the services I recommended above.
```